# Populate data in EJS Template script tag

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I'm working through adding the ChartJS library to a Node web app and am having trouble dynamically passing through data from a "Player" model.  Here's the script tag portion of the EJS template:

```
<script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    let pointAvg = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    console.log(pointAvg)
    let playerStatChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Points',
                data: pointAvg,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(149,16,16, 0.4)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Points: <%= player.name %>",
                fontSize: 25
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

And here's an example of a "player" in the Player model:

```
  _id: 5e94ac2d81fa5428b0323fc1,
  name: 'Naz Mitrou-Long',
  season: [
    {
      year: '2012-2013',
      grade: 'Freshman',
      gp: 18,
      gs: 0,
      mpg: 6.9,
      fg: 0.348,
      tp: 0.278,
      ft: 1,
      rpg: 0.8,
      apg: 1,
      spg: 0.3,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 1.4
    },
    {
      year: '2013-2014',
      grade: 'Sophomore',
      gp: 36,
      gs: 7,
      mpg: 20.3,
      fg: 0.432,
      tp: 0.4,
      ft: 0.643,
      rpg: 1.6,
      apg: 1.1,
      spg: 0.2,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 7.1
    },
    {
      year: '2014-2015',
      grade: 'Junior',
      gp: 34,
      gs: 33,
      mpg: 27.5,
      fg: 0.449,
      tp: 0.391,
      ft: 0.755,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 2,
      spg: 0.8,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 10.1
    },
    {
      year: '2015-2016',
      grade: 'R. Senior',
      gp: 8,
      gs: 8,
      mpg: 31.6,
      fg: 0.425,
      tp: 0.291,
      ft: 0.6,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 1.9,
      spg: 0.6,
      bpg: 0.3,
      ppg: 12
    },
    {
      year: '2016-2017',
      grade: 'Senior',
      gp: 35,
      gs: 35,
      mpg: 33.3,
      fg: 0.473,
      tp: 0.384,
      ft: 0.795,
      rpg: 4.6,
      apg: 2.7,
      spg: 1.2,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 15.1
    }
  ]
```

This player data has already been passed through to the client side from the Node server and is available for use. Currently I pass through other values to the template like so:

```
<h1><%= player.name %></h1>
```

How can I populate that static `pointAvg` array with the `ppg` from each object in the `season` array and make it dynamic instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
var vPlayer = '<%- JSON.stringify(player) %>';
    console.log(vPlayer);
</script>
```

Now you have the model data. Use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data from nodejs into client side script tag with EJS. Use this method.

```
<script>
    let data='<%- JSON.stringify(player) %>';
    data= JSON.parse(data);
</script>
```

Stringify will return your Object string-ed. Parse will convert it back into an Object for further use.