# Is it a bad idea to use the meta tag in HTML to specify custom metadata for retrieval with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Whereas the following code works, I question whether or not it is bad practise to use it? I could achieve the same with a div inside the body. However, seeing as I am trying to get **metadata** from my html, it would seem logical to use the **meta**-tag. Is this okay, or can it have unexpected issues?

My use case is when information is passed down from the server through EJS and I don't want to have to make a redundant second request to my server from my JS to get the data that is already passed down when rendering the HTML.

```js
const user = document.getElementById("meta_user");
console.log(user.getAttribute("data-content"));
```

```html
<head>
  <meta data-name="user" data-content="{ name: 'test' }" id="meta_user">
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what EJS is but can't you simply use search parameters in the URL? (the `?data=value` part of the URL) It would seem more standard.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie EJS just lets you do JS-like operations and access information you pass from your server when rendering HTML so I can do something like `if (user) { <p>Welcome user.name</p> }` inside my html file. Thats why it would be convenient to just chuck that user object into a tag so I can access it in my scripts as well. Search parameters is definitely a good alternative though.

Comment: I haven't seen anybody use a meta tag, but perhaps a hidden input?

Comment: Not necessarily a bad idea or bad practice, but certainly unusual. Normally one would just output a `<script>const user = {name: 'test'};</script>`, if JS is meant to be the only consumer of the data. However *if* you want to use a `<meta>` tag instead, you should use the [standard attributes for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) not `id` and `data-*`. Also use JSON syntax instead of object literal syntax (which you'd have to `eval`) for non-textual data.

Comment: Why not put it on the body element or the relevant script element? This seems needlessly convoluted and potentially confusing to other developers.

Comment: @Bergi A script like this would have been the best solution. However, unfortunatly, EJS cannot be used inside the script tag.

Comment: @mykaf Just curious, why a hidden input exactly? Is it better than a hidden div anyhow, or just a convention?

Comment: So you can easily access its via JS and submit it in a form if needed. Div elements don't get submitted in forms. Input signals to me that this is useful data and not just text.

Comment: @OscarR [yes it can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61874205/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi It works! Thank you so much for that, I always thought it wasn't possible because using <%= %> directly like you do outside scripts didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element):

> Exactly one of the `name`, `http-equiv`, `charset`, and `itemprop` attributes must be specified.
>
> If either `name`, `http-equiv`, or `itemprop` is specified, then the `content` attribute must also be specified. Otherwise, it must be omitted.

Your use is missing all of these attributes. You should come up with a `name` attribute that describes this use, and make sure it doesn't conflict with any of the standard names, and preferably none of the names on the [MetaExtensions wiki](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) (you could also search there to see if something similar is already registered).

Comment: That's helpful, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I originally voted to close the question as opinion-based. Then when I found the specification, I decided to summarize the issues with the way they're using it as an answer.